# Response.Redirect(relative url) fails after intrasite moved to another computer

Tags: asp.net, redirect, response

I have moved a intranet site that has been chugging away for the last 6 years on a Windows 7 machine using VS 2010 (framework 3.5) to newer computer running Windows 10 using VS 2015.  I am trying to do as little mods as possible and am baffled by this problem.

The IIS entry for the website is linked to a folder on the development machine and is the same folder used by the vs 2015 editor. It's an asp.net with VB code behind.

*(Note: http links broken to satisfy # of links restrictions)*

*UPDATE:  The redirect works fine with the original code when running on the localhost.  When I access the site from another computer on the network the redirect fails with the escaped characters in the URL and the extra "/pm" folder in the URL and Physical Path.*

...Good...

Running the site inside VS using localhost the redirects work as advertised.

... Bad ...

....After publishing the site and accessing it outside of Visual Studio...

The "Response.Redirect"'s use relative URL's as well and is failing since the move with a 404.0 error response.  Here is the redirect code inside the button's Click handler:

> Response.Redirect("~/pm/pmClaimBin.aspx?BinNbr=?BinNbr=29)

The browser shows the results below with escaped chars and an extra "/pm" added to the URL:

> http://192.168.0.7:81/pm/%2fpm%2fpmClaimBin.aspx%3fBinNbr%3d29

The error page shows the following....

> Requested URL  http://192.168.0.7:81/pm/pm/pmClaimBin.aspx?BinNbr=29
>
> Physical Path  C:\inetpub\wwwBwe\pm\pm\pmClaimBin.aspx?BinNbr=29

The path should be:  C:\inetpub\wwwBwe\pm\pmClaimBin.aspx?BinNbr=29

Removing the "~" produced the exact same results for both the good & bad example.

So now I have to ask...

**Why the now escaped characters in the browser's URL?**

**Why the extra "/pm" (folder) being thrown in?**

Comment: I don't know what's happening with your redirects. However, there is two things wrong with Response.Redirect("~/pmClaimBin.aspx?BinNbr=?BinNbr=29). 1. The string is not correctly quoted. 2.you can't have two question marks in a URL

Comment: My bad.  I make a typo in recreating the redirect above.  I have corrected my original post.